# Limit and Landau little o

Tags: real-analysis

Let's consider $f$ and $g$ two functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's have $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) =\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)$

Now can we conclude that :

$$f(x) = g(x)+o_{x\to x_0}(g(x))$$

<del>We got : $$\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(x)\over g(x)} = 1 = \lim_{x\to x_o} >{g(x)+o(g(x))\over g(x)}$$</del>

[EDIT  : This is very wrong ! As pointed out by MathematicsStudent1122 indeed :$$\lim f(x) = \lim g(x) \nRightarrow  \lim{f(x)\over g(x)} = 1$$
As a side note using "we got" was a poor choice as it was not something given but a conclusion I made]

But is it enough ?

Please provide rigorous proof or a counter example. Thanks !

Comment: The limit operation preserves the four arithmetic operation, provided only the denominator should be nonzero on an open ball when it comes to division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x$ near (but not equal to) $x_0$.

The conclusion equivalently states that

$$\lim \frac{f(x) - g(x)}{g(x)} = \lim \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1\right) = 0$$

0r $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$

Hence, it's sufficient to find $f,g$ such that $\lim [f(x) - g(x)] = 0$ but $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \neq 1$.

A simple example of this is $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Definition: $H(x)=o(J(x))$ as $x\to y\;$ iff for every $s>0$ there exists $r>0$ such that for all $x\in (-r+y,r+y)$ \ $\{y\}$ we have $(|H(x)|<s|J(x)|).$

It may be that for every $r>0$ there exists $x\in (-r+y,r+y)$ \ $\{y\}$ with $J(x)=0,$ so we cannot conclude that $\lim_{x\to y}H(x)/J(x)=0.$

For example, $y=0,$ $J(x)=x\sin (1/x),$ and $H(x)=x^2\sin (1/x)$ for $x\ne 0.$